# Remove <b:includable> in Bloggers Template

Tags: xhtml, blogger

So I managed to narrow down the template by only adding the 'main' and 'post' b:includable under the Blog widget and Main section but it kept getting reset every time I try to save it. I want to save it as it is if possible.

```
<b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='no'>
  <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog' visible='true'>

 <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
  <b:if cond='data:mobile == &quot;false&quot;'>
   <div>
     <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'><!-- Start Post Loop -->
       <div class='post-outer'>
       <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
       <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
         <b:include data='post' name='comment_picker'/>
       </b:if>
        </div>
     </b:loop>
   </div>
   <b:include name='nextprev'/>
 </b:if>
 </b:includable>

  <b:includable id='post' var='post'>
  <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
     <data:post.timestamp/>
  <p><data:post.body/></p>
  </b:includable>

  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete all unnecessary b:includables. But can roll them: just add slash at the end of the title of includable.

Example:

```
<b:includable id='shareButtons' var='post'/>
```